# When executing .findOne (), no field with relation is shown

Tags: typeorm

These is my table:

```
@Entity('localidades')
export class Localidades {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
    nombre: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Provincias)
    @JoinColumn({name: "idprovincia"})
    provincia: string;
    
}
```

This is my query:

```
async find(id: number): Promise<Localidades> {
    const tabla = await this.repository.findOne(id)
    return tabla
  }
```

Obtained result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Localidad 1",
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Localidad 1",
    "idprovincia": 1
}
```

I need the province id field to show it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by defining my table as follows:

```
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
    nombre: string;
                                                                              
    @Column()
    idprovincia: number;
    
    @ManyToOne(type => Provincias, {
      cascade: true,
      nullable: false,
    })
    @JoinColumn({name: "idprovincia"})
    provincia: string;
```

And in the consultation

```
async find(id: number): Promise<Localidades> {
    const tabla = await this.repository.findOne(id)
    return tabla
  }
```

I hope that it would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `relations` to your query:

```
async find(id: number): Promise<Localidades> {
    const tabla = await this.repository.findOne(id, { relations: ['provincia'] })
    return tabla
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Gave back: `"id": 1,
    "nombre": "Localidad 1",
    "provincia": {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Provincia 1"
    }`